# HTML Calculator not calculating right

Tags: html, calculator

I can't get this to calculate correctly need some advice and I need it to add decimals.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
      <input type="number" id="a" value="">
      <input type="hidden" id="b" value="5.75%">
      <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/nvp8g5jg/  What's the problem?

Comment: Are you looking for parseFloat instead of parseInt?

Comment: its only supposed to add 5.75 percent to the number inputed if you put 200 in there it still says 5

Comment: ParseFloat works but when I go to a number above 100 it does not calculate correctly

Comment: You want to add 5.75 to the number being input and display it, or display 5.75% of the number being input? Give us an example of the input and what the output should be.

Comment: it is eventually supposed to  take the total amount and give a total bassed on the amount inputted so it would look like this example: 100 + 5.57% = 105.75  The number I want to display though is the fee so in this example it would be $5.75 if the example was $200 it would display $11.50

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I believe the calculation you want to use really is:

```
parseFloat(b.value)/100*parseFloat(a.value)
```

Example:

```js
<form oninput="x.value='$'+(parseFloat(b.value)/100*parseFloat(a.value)).toFixed(2)">
<input type="number" id="a" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="b" value="5.75%">
<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```